# Apply changes across the page. Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have these lines of Jquery code to manipulate the HTML

```
$('#Remarks li:gt(1)').wrapAll('<ul class="btmRow" />');
$("#btRowMargin").appendTo("#Remarks");
$('#Remarks ul:lt(2)').wrapAll('<li class="btmRow" />');
```

I want  the above code to take effect across the page where ever #Remarks is present. For that I wrote

```
$.each($("#Remarks"), function() {
    $('#Remarks li:gt(1)').wrapAll('<ul class="btmRow" />');
    $("#btRowMargin").appendTo("#Remarks ");
    $('#Remarks ul:lt(2)').wrapAll('<li class="btmRow" />');
});
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.

[JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/grMNZ/)

Originally HTML looks like this

```
<li>
    <ul id="Remarks" class="Remarks">
       <li class="Header  soldBKG">Showing Information</li>
       <li><p><b>Remarks:</b></p></li>
       <li><span>Occupant Name</span><span class="data">Listing Office</span></li>
       <li><span>Occupancy/Show</span><span class="data">Listing Agent</span></li>
       <li><span>Occupant Type</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
       <li><span>Occupant Phone</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
       <li><span>Other Phone Number</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>

    </ul>
    <ul class="btmRow MarginFix" id="btmRowMarginFix">
        <li></li>
        <li><span>Phone To Show</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
        <li><span>LockBox Location</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
        <li><span>LockBox Type</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
        <li><span>Showing Access</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

After applying the jquery the HTML looks like :

```
<li>
    <ul id="Remarks" class="Remarks">
       <li class="Header  soldBKG">Showing Information</li>
       <li><p><b>Remarks:</b></p></li>
       <li class="btmRow">
         <ul class="btmRow">
            <li><span>Occupant Name</span><span class="data">Listing Office</span></li>
            <li><span>Occupancy/Show</span><span class="data">Listing Agent</span></li>
            <li><span>Occupant Type</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
            <li><span>Occupant Phone</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
            <li><span>Other Phone Number</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
         </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="btmRow MarginFix" id="btmRowMarginFix">
        <li></li>
        <li><span>Phone To Show</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
        <li><span>LockBox Location</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
        <li><span>LockBox Type</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
        <li><span>Showing Access</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

But I want like this :

```
<li>
    <ul id="Remarks" class="Remarks">
       <li class="Header  soldBKG">Showing Information</li>
       <li><p><b>Remarks:</b></p></li>
       <li class="btmRow">
         <ul class="btmRow">
            <li><span>Occupant Name</span><span class="data">Listing Office</span></li>
            <li><span>Occupancy/Show</span><span class="data">Listing Agent</span></li>
            <li><span>Occupant Type</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
            <li><span>Occupant Phone</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
            <li><span>Other Phone Number</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
         </ul>

         <ul class="btmRow MarginFix" id="btmRowMarginFix">
            <li></li>
            <li><span>Phone To Show</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
            <li><span>LockBox Location</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
            <li><span>LockBox Type</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
            <li><span>Showing Access</span><span class="data">N/A</span></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>

  </li>
```

Comment: #Remarks is an element id and must be unique for a page; so an each manipulate only an element; are you using a class instead .Remarks ? Can you provide an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: Please show us your HTML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here a liste of your misstake.

**1:** Id's must be unique, so when you have a the jQuery selector `$('#Remarks')`, it return only 1 element. No loop in the each. Changing you id with class will make a loop.

Side note: when looping through jquery element, you can use `.each()` like that : `$(selector).each(function(){})`. The way you are using it now is for arrays or objects.

**2:** Inside the `.each()`, you need to use this, else your are reselecting every element and have no "real controle" :

```
$('.Remarks').each(function(){
     var $this = $(this) //Caching the object for optimisation
     $this.find('li:gt(1)').wrapAll('<ul class="btmRow" />');
     //this line has to change, see point 3
     $this.find('ul:lt(2)').wrapAll('<li class="btmRow" />');
})
```

**3:** This is a guess, but this line :

```
$("#btRowMargin").appendTo('#Remarks');
```

will probably have to change. You'll probly need to use some DOM traversal function but i can't tell you what since we don't have access to your DOM. but it will finish with `.appendTo($this)`.

```
$this.siblings('.bottomRow.MarginFix').appendTo($this.find('li :eq(2)'));
```

Comment: Thank u. The appendTo() doesn't seem to be working. I updated the question. Pls take a look.

Comment: For the third line I tried doing : $(".btmRow MarginFix").appendTo('$this'); but not working.

Comment: Try `$('.MarginFix').appendTo($this.find('li.btmRow'))`

Comment: Just realized i had a typo in the each, but it work here : http://jsfiddle.net/Qfpvm/ What is your code doing?

Comment: The append Happens to the last .MarginFix only.

Comment: I am so stupid. I forgot you had more than 1 `.Remarks`. Try this : `$this.siblings('.MarginFix').appendTo($this.find('li.btmRow'))`

Comment: Thank you. I could make it work with the following code $this.siblings('.MarginFix').appendTo($this.find('li :eq(2)'))

Answer (score 2):

Change it to a **class** instead of an **id** ..

As `id` is supposed to be unique on a HTML page.

And then use the `this` context to apply those changes to only the current element in iteration

```
$(".Remarks").each(function () {
    $('li:gt(1)', this).wrapAll('<ul class="btmRow" />');
    $("#btRowMargin").appendTo(this);
    $('ul:lt(2)', this).wrapAll('<li class="btmRow" />');
});
```

Similarly if element with id `btRowMargin` is in multiple places replace that with the class and use the `this` context for that as well.

Comment: Sushanth Thank u. The appendTo() doesn't seem to be working. I updated the question. Pls take a look.